# Crop image in a fragment

Tags: java, android, image, crop

I'm using this library for cropping images https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/3487
I have a problem when trying to crop an image from a fragment and not from a regular activity and it doesn't work, even though I do the exact thing,
this is my `onActivityResult`:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {



            CropImage.activity(data.getData())
                    .setCropShape(CropImageView.CropShape.OVAL)
                    .setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.OFF)
                    .setAutoZoomEnabled(false)
                    .start(getContext(), FeedFragment.this);

        }

        if (requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
            CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);
            try {
                Uri resultUri = result.getUri();
                InputStream is = getActivity().getContentResolver().openInputStream(resultUri);
                Bitmap photoBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
                imgButton.setImageBitmap(photoBitmap);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and the problem is in this line:

```
  .start(getContext(), FeedFragment.this);
```

the error:

```
Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=65537, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://media/external/images/media/5560 flg=0x1 (has extras) }} to activity {apps.berant.knowu/apps.berant.knowu.MainActivity}: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {apps.berant.knowu/com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImageActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

thanks for the help :)

Comment: Did you at least read an exception? *have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml*

Comment: The result data is getting dumped in the Parent Activities onActivityResult() .  Read the following : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6147884/onactivityresult-is-not-being-called-in-fragment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add line `AndroidManifest.xml`

`<activity android:name="com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImageActivity"/>`

Answer (score 1):

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv_house"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
```

In Fragment

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.iv_house:
    if (CropImage.isExplicitCameraPermissionRequired(getActivity())) {
        requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, CropImage.CAMERA_CAPTURE_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE);
    } else {
        CropImage.startPickImageActivity(getActivity());
    }
    break;
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == CropImage.PICK_IMAGE_CHOOSER_REQUEST_CODE) {
        Uri imageUri = CropImage.getPickImageResultUri(getActivity(), data);
        if (CropImage.isReadExternalStoragePermissionsRequired(getActivity(), imageUri)) {
            mCropImageUri = imageUri;
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, CropImage.PICK_IMAGE_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE);    
        } else {
            Intent intent = CropImage.activity(imageUri)
                .setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON)
                .setFixAspectRatio(true)
                .setAspectRatio(2,1)
                .getIntent(getActivity());
            getActivity().startActivityForResult(intent, CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    }

    if (requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
        CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Uri resultUri = result.getUri();
            selectedFilePath = resultUri.getPath();
            imageView.setImageURI(resultUri);
        } else if (resultCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_RESULT_ERROR_CODE) {
            Exception error = result.getError();
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    //super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if (requestCode == CropImage.CAMERA_CAPTURE_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            CropImage.startPickImageActivity(getActivity());
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Cancelling, required permissions are not granted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    if (requestCode == CropImage.PICK_IMAGE_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (mCropImageUri != null && grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Intent intent = CropImage.activity(mCropImageUri)
                .setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON)
                .setFixAspectRatio(true)
                .setAspectRatio(2,1)
                .getIntent(getActivity());
            getActivity().startActivityForResult(intent, CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Cancelling, required permissions are not granted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

In Activity

```
private Uri mCropImageUri;  

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    //super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.container);
    fragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

In AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity
    android:name="com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImageActivity"
    android:theme="@style/Base.Theme.AppCompat" />
```

Answer (score 0):

As it's mentioned in docs, I just simply added this to manifest:

```
<activity
        android:name="com.yalantis.ucrop.UCropActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"/>
```